# Multi-site wordpress redirect between https subdomains via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have
https:// sub1 . demo.com

and would like to redirect via htaccess to
https:// sub2 .  demo.com

the site is a multi-site wordpress build

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub1.demo.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://sub2.demo.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

Thanks in advance folks im new to asking the answers are usually all there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf and then add this in root_ folder/.htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sub2.yoursite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to let you know at the time this one did work cheers